# Controlling the AOSP power-reporting functionality from new code

Tags: android, android-source, i2c, android-powermanager

In the Android Open Source Project, where would I add/override the code which tells Android about the battery level and AC power?

I need to poll a component on an i2c bus to get this information, on my board, and pass it to Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your Android version:

**Oreo and Newer**

You have to replace the existing [Health HAL](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/health) service with a custom one that provides the information you want. You don't have to write the service from scratch but change the provided [dummy implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/refs/heads/master/health/2.0/default/).

**Nougat and Older**

These version do not yet have a Health HAL. You have to update the `healthd` directly in [system/core/healthd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/healthd).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have specified Android 6 in the question.  I've found aosp/system/core/healthd/BatteryMonitor.cpp which looks like a good place to start.